# Commanding property not found on viewmodel xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, command

While i tried to implement a simple command to raise property of progress bar within listview through command fired in viewmodel assing to this page. I don't know what to do next becouse the progress bar don't increment when i'm call command from imagebutton assing to same object ?.

Output after clicking imagebutton

```
Bidning: 'IncrementCommand property not found on AppDemo.Models.SampleObject, target property XamarinForms.ImageButtonCommand'
```

A code from Viewmodel:

```
    public ICommand IncrementCommand { get; }
    public MainViewModel(IPageServices pageServices)
    {
        this._pageServices = pageServices; 

        Wastes = GetObjects();
        IncrementCommand = new Command(async () => await IncrementObject());

    }
    async Task IncrementObject()
    {
        await objectServices.IncrementObject(object);
        OnPropertyChanged("SampleCounter");
    }
```

Code from service where Task is called

```
    public Task IncrementObject(ObjectModel object)
    {
        object.ObjectCounter += .1;
        return objectRepository.Save(object);
    }
```

Model inherit INotifyPropertyChanged from Observable object

```
public class SampleModel: ObservableObject
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string SampleIcon{ get; set; }
    public double SampleCounter{ get; set; } 
}
```

Code from MainPage xaml file

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                     ProgressColor="#614c96"
                                     Progress="{Binding ObjectCounter}"                                         
                                     />
                        <ImageButton x:Name="iconButton"
                                     Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                     WidthRequest="100"
                                     HeightRequest="100"
                                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                                     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                     Source="{Binding ObjectIcon}"
                                     Command="{x:Binding IncrementCommand}">
                        </ImageButton>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Coede form page code-behind

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var pageServices = new PageServices();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel(pageServices);

    }
```

Can i ask for some explenation of my mistake ? Thank you

Comment: the BindingContext for each item in your ListView is SampleModel, not the ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and the error message is not consistent. I'm going to assume that in this error:

> Bidning: 'IncrementCommand property not found on AppDemo.Models.SampleObject, target property XamarinForms.ImageButtonCommand'

`SampleObject` is now named `SampleModel`.

Like Jason pointed out in a comment, the binding context for each item in your list is different than the binding context for the whole page. Whenever you use a list, the binding context of each item will be scoped to the item in that cell.

To be able to reach something outside of that, you will have to use a reference. First, give a name to your `ListView` like this: `<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ...>`.

Then, for your `ImageButton`, change the `Command` to be this: `<ImageButton Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView}, Path=BindingContext.IncrementCommand}">`

By adding the source and referencing the `ListView`, we now scope the binding to whatever we specify in `Path`. So we suddenly can access the properties of the `ListView` and access its `BindingContext` (being the `SampleModel`) and inside that context access the command we are after, in this case, `IncrementCommand`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you , i really appreciate your answear. But it's comes out with unhandled exception about object referenced after clicking a imagebutton :(

Comment: What is the code in the command? And what is the exact exception message?

Comment: Command calls IncrementObject Task which calls service Task InceremntObject. code i posted with this question showing it

Comment: Did you put in a breakpoint? My guess is `object` is null right now. Change your `ImageButton` to this: `<ImageButton Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView}, Path=BindingContext.IncrementCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}">`. By adding the `CommandParameter` you specify what is supplied as a parameter for your command. So, the value of your `object` parameter. `{Binding .}` indicates that you want to supply the whole object that is bound to your cell as a parameter.

Comment: Commanding as followed your explanation works well but my code somewhere is missing something becouse i tried with simply DisplayAlert Dialog after clicking on this and work as expected :) Thank you very much for your time

Comment: See my last comment :)

Comment: Generaly mine main goal of this is to  click that image then  navigate to next page assing to model, and send parameter which is string for Background of that page.  The exception is like this:

Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I think i just post one more question :) Thank you for your time :)